# Why is the conflict in the UK Labour Party described by some as the “chicken coup”?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In the current conflict in the UK Labour Party, some are using the phrase *Chicken Coup*:

[Morning Star](http://www.morningstaronline.co.uk/a-c198-Chicken-Coup-rebels-are-running-out-of-room/): *Chicken Coup rebels are running out of room*

[David Graeber in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jul/05/political-establishment-momentum-jeremy-corbyn): *As the rolling catastrophe of what’s already being called the “chicken coup” against the Labour leadership winds down,...*

[Weblog “Another angry voice”](http://anotherangryvoice.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/the-ineptitude-of-failed-corbyn-coup.html): *The failed "chicken coup" demonstrates that the Blairites aren't even good at the stuff they used to be.*

A [Chicken coop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_coop) is *a building where female chickens are kept*.  A [Coup d`état](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_d'%C3%A9tat) is *the illegal and overt seizure of a state by the military or other elites within the state apparatus.*

I can understand why Corbyn supporters may choose to use the word “Coup”, but why “Chicken coup”?

Comment: It seems to me a derogatory pun.  "Chicken" where I come from is a taunt issued to cowards.

Comment: Presumably Corbyn supporters also wish to suggest that opponents who want him to stand down, but are not mounting a formal leadership challenge, are chicken.  Is this actually being used other than in propaganda (a proper gander presumably being the opposite of a chicken here?)

Comment: @TimLymington In the original meaning, of course it is propaganda — clearly the choice to describe the rebellion in the Parliamentary Labour Party as a “coup” aims to influence the opinions of whoever reads it, which means it is by definition propaganda.  However the word propaganda itself has become pejorative, and perhaps choosing to use the word propaganda is itself an act of propaganda?  I haven't seen it used in any articles that weren't explicitly opinionated, if that answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

According to Mike Sivier's [blog](http://voxpoliticalonline.com/2016/06/30/chickencoup-ringleaders-are-fighting-amongst-themselves-over-challenge-to-corbyn/):

> The rebellion in the Parliamentary Labour Party has been labelled the #ChickenCoup on social media because, while its members are trying to mount a coup against Mr Corbyn, **they are afraid of revealing their treachery** to members of their own constituency parties, who support the Labour leader.

and **coup** I assume means both **coup d'état** and implies perhaps that Westminster is somewhat like a **chicken-coop** where MPs behave like (stupid) chickens.

Comment: Given that the motion of "no confidence" in Jeremy Corbyn was passed by a vote of 176 to 40 among Labour MPs, and that the names of all the MPs voting for and against are publicly known, I fail to see how they are "afraid of revealing their treachery".

Comment: @ws2 Some MPs went public but it was a secret ballot so perhaps some MPs voted against Corbyn surreptitiously  "The party’s parliamentarians voted 172 to 40 against Mr Corbyn’s leadership **in a secret ballot** on Tuesday afternoon. There were four spoilt ballots in the contest, while 13 MPs did not vote." http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/jeremy-corbyn-loses-no-confidence-vote-among-labour-mps-by-176-to-40-a7107826.html

Comment: Fowl play is suspected.

Answer (score 0):

The "Red Flag" is a traditional song of the Labour Movement.
It contains the lines "Though cowards flinch and traitors sneer"
A synonym for coward is chicken.
A bunch of "sneering" cowards launch a coup.
It is, therefore, a chicken coup.

Comment: Are not the Corbyn supporters rather like the Brexit voters - namely "turkeys voting for Christmas"!

Comment: Nothing to do with "Corbyn supporters." If you can't understand that you will not be able to grasp the importance of resisting the "chicken coup."